# Set key in a spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Tengo un dataframe de spark (no es un rdd) en el que una de las columnas se sabe que tiene valores únicos. Me parece que tiene sentido pensar que algunas operaciones que se puedan ejecutar sobre el dataframe puedan aprovechar este hecho para optimizar las operaciones. ¿Hay alguna forma de indicar a Spark este hecho para que lo pueda utilizar?

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Hi, this is [es.so]. Please translate you question to the official site language: Spanish. Otherwise, your question will be closed. Thanks. Hola esto es [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al idioma oficial del sitio: Castellano. De lo contrario, tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos